# Magento 1.9.1 PayPal Express review page is empty

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout

I am using Magento version 1.9.1.0 and the module FireGento_MageSetup version 2.2.2.

Furthermore I am using a custom theme.

If a customer pay by PayPal the shop redirects him after the shipping information step in onepage checkout to PayPal. After logging in in PayPal the customer will be redirect to the review page of the shop. But this page has not any content, so the customer can not place the order.

Can anybody help me please??

Comment: Try to enable the errors visible in frontend and check if any error is visible?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. In my case, it was simply because I'd disabled the `Mage_Paypal` extension under `System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output`.

Answer (score 3):

if you will enable errors you will see there is Fatal error: Call to a member function setFieldNamePrefix() on a non-object on paypal/express/review.phtml on line 28 of custom template.

quick solution is, delete review.phtml from theme file and it will read from base directory but this may disturb design of order review page.

proper solution is, copy review.phtml from base and fix design according to theme.

Comment: This solution works. this answer should be accepted.